# using systemd without journal

Tags: logging, syslog, systemd, journal

Is it possible to run systemd with (r)syslog instead of journal?
This would probably at least require, that the (r)syslog daemon listens again to the /dev/log socket and additionally to /run/systemd/journal/dev-log. Furthermore the (r)syslog daemon must be able to process native journal log messages.
Is there any (r)syslog extension which can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The journal is the only mandatory component of systemd outside PID1.

You can use any syslog implementation you wish and set Storage=none in journald.conf to have the closest to a journal-less system. This will however make systemctl status output very limited or useless.

Comment: Also, this will cause extra context switch to carry a log. One for systemd-journald, other for the log daemon of your choice.